# Excel Input letters to value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, input

I want to assign fixed values to input letters. I'm able to do that with `VLOOKUP`, but the case is that I need this for 100s of records.

For example, I have given values to:

```
S=50
U=60
P=70
E=140
R=24
```

Now all I want is as an input letter to work. Suppose in A1 I want to add **SU**, so it should sum up automatically in C1 (Result) 110 and in A2 I added **PER** C2=234, etc.

Adding a formula to every letter seems impossible. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you only ever using 2 characters i.e. SU or UP or could it be more like SUPER...

Comment: Of course it will use more letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the following works if you have no repetitions in your text (per your sample data)

1. Generate a table for the value of each letter:

[image]

2. Assuming your text is in column `A`, enter the following formula in `B2`:

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,J$2:J$6,""))),K$2:K$6)
   ```

Comment: Worked but the problem is that it will contain repetitive  letters like my name iLLeach.

Comment: The provided formula sums multiple ocurrences of letters, so for example `SU` results in a sum of `110` and `SUSU` in `220`. If this is not the desired result, can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1499628/edit) to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You may use Excel's inbuilt Unicode character set.

[To know in detail about Unicode charters go to Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Alphabetic_Presentation_Forms)

Type the followings in your excel sheet: **B1 & B2 contain array formulae**

`A1 = SUPER`   `B1 {=SUM(UNICODE(MID(A1,{1,2,3,4,5},1)))}`

`A2 = super`   `B2 {=SUM(UNICODE(MID(A2,{1,2,3,4,5},1)))}`

one more tip: For finding the Unicode value of every alphabet/ charters small and capital. type them and use formula Unicode().

Comment: worked like charm but I don't need Unicode values, I need to assign custom values to let's say all alphabets

Comment: Thank you all for responding nicely.

Let me be more specific about my question please have a look at given screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrr11.jpg

Comment: above formula is solving correctly... `=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,J$2:J$6,""))),K$2:K$6)` ... I see your screenshot... Duplicates **are not** allowed in your `Alphabet` column but duplicate/ triplicate **are** allowed in the `Input` column, for example, your name...